Is there a unget() method for putting back everything extracted by std::getline back into an istream?
I am extracting each full row of a csv file using std::getline:
for (std::string row; std::getline(is, row); )  // reads entire row in csv file
{
    if (std::ranges::count(row, ',') != Temp_reading::read_parameters - 1) // checks if row has right amount of columns
    {
        std::cerr << "Row: " << row << " contains too many columns in csv file" << "\n";
        is.unget(); // Want this to put entire row back into istream
        is.clear(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return;
     } 
     // does other stuff if the row has right amount of columns
 }

In this case is.unget() will only put back the last character in the istream. Is there a way to make is.unget() put back the entire row? Or  is there another simple way to achieve the same?

No, not directly. unget is also limited to (possibly) a few chars in the input buffer. If it is a file (and not the console) you might be able to save a position with tellg() and restore it with seekg.

Consider using an intermediate buffer in between the stream and the parser. Read from the stream into the buffer, then parse the buffer.  If the parse fails, you still have the buffer to look at until the next stream read.

unget only makes the most recently extracted single character available. You can use seekg to rewind by the size of the extracted string
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream input{"hello\nworld"};
    std::string word;
    std::getline(input,word);
    std::cout << word <<"\n";
    input.seekg(-word.size());
    std::getline(input,word);
    std::cout << word <<"\n";
}

Live Demo

However, I have doubts whether this is the right approach for your use case. From the CSV file the row needs to be extracted anyhow. Instead of rewinding the input stream just to extract the same line again you should consider to use the already extracted string.

The function which the loop is a part of takes an istream by reference which the caller supplies. My intention was that putting the row back into the stream gives the caller the option to look closer at the badly formatted row.

@user3612 you could return them the string, or throw an exception which has the row attached. Anyhow, thats not essential for the answer. The code shows to do what you want

@user3612 I mean it depends. Reading user input is tricky and reacting on faulty input even more. In my projects, the best I can do is terminate and produce a nice message, though I suppose thats not the common case

Also notable: this only works on seekable streams. It doesn’t work on, for example, character devices like the console or pipes.
